# Using google cart gadget locally

Tags: javascript, google-checkout

You might be aware that google checkout is closing in Novemeber, and rather than spending hours writing a new cart I'm hoping it's possible to move the google cart gadget to local...

I have it running on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4SVRx/5/

But as soon as I make that javascript local I get nothing

http://jsfiddle.net/4SVRx/6/

Is it not possible to use the code locally?

links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code. There's a sizeable amount of code in jsfiddle I don't want to post it here

```
<div class="basket">
```

etc.......

Comment: I don't see the error currently (especially since the console doesn't show any …), but what you are doing there is not a good idea copyright-wise …

Comment: i'm just copying the code and linking it to google wallet, which comes under "owner of copies" i'm not selling, misrepresenting or altering it